# Is there a way to create a traditional network with mininet then replace some of its nodes with SDN?

Tags: python, networking, hybrid, sdn, mininet

I have set up the entire environment to run *mininet* using an *Ubuntu* image on *VirtualBox*. I also found a *JSON* graph topology which I run with *Python* to simulate it in mininet (I use *PuTTy* for remote access from Windows..)

I read before that using the command `sudo mn --controller=none` 
creates a non-SDN simulation. This is not bad for a start, but is there another way of doing that? And if so, how is it possible to remove a specific node and replace it with an *SDN switch* to test the network performance?

Many thanks in advance.

**Set up used:**

Windows 10, Oracle VM Virtual Machine, Ubuntu, Mininet, NetworkX, Python, WinTCP..PuTTy..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You start a normal SDN network with the desired topology, and you:

1. set the forwarding-rules on the 'non' SDN-nodes to live forever (so the controller is never asked for new/expired rules), and
2. leave the rest of the node under the control of the controller.